# is there any way for minifying "myProject.styles.css" that generated by ASP.net 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, minify

I have file named '_componentA.cshtml', for using scoped CSS, I added '_componentA.cshtml.css' inside the same folder of component and after that I added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/@(nameof(MyProject)).styles.css" />
```

into my component cshtml file.

'MyProject.styles.css' is not exist in root of project and create during the build so i can't use 'bundler and minifier' extension for minify

is there any way for minify this file and use minified file in website?

i try to pass 'MyProject.styles.css' to 'bundler and minifier' extension and use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/@(nameof(MyProject)).styles.min.css" />
```

but it not work.

i am **NOT** using blazor  and component made by razor veiw